# Merge polygons using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

As you can see below, I have two polygons with sides. Basically 2 triangles with their respective coordinates. See:

```js
function initialize() {
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  var polygonCoords = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
     new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
     new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370)
  ];
  

  for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
     bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: bounds.getCenter(),
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
  });


  var triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangle1.setMap(map);
  
  var polygonCoords2 = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
     new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
     new google.maps.LatLng(14.979063, -83.500871)
  ];

  var triangule2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords2,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangule2.setMap(map);
  
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas2" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw"></div>
</body>
```

I would like to merge the two triangles so that the risk does not appear in the middle between the two, thus making a polygon with 4 sides or 4 coordinates. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: is it expected that the coordinates that are to be merged into one (i.e. points on Puerto Rico and Florida) are always the same coordinate just part of a different polyline? Hope that made sense

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could merge the arrays and remove the duplicates? Something like:

```
var newPolygon = polygonCoords.concat(polygonCoords2);
```

And then remove the duplicate coordinates (I took this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/easiest-way-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-javascript-array) post):

```
var sorted_arr = newPolygon.slice().sort(); // You can define the comparing function here. 
                                     // JS by default uses a crappy string compare.
                                     // (we use slice to clone the array so the
                                     // original array won't be modified)
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < newPolygon.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Then replace `paths: polygonCoords,` with `paths: results,`